# Is there a possibility to pass variable in Exclude parameter of xcopy command

Tags: powershell, xcopy

So basically I am looking for some way to pass variable to exclude parameter of xcopy command.

Is it possible? Because it does work for source and destination path

So something like this

```
$excludeFilesPath = 'excludeFilePath'
xcopy "$($deploySourceRoot)*" $deployRoot /E /Y /Q /Exclude:$excludeFilesPath
```

So as you can see it works for source and destination but as soon as I give the exclude path in the same way it gives me this error

`Invalid number of parameters`

Comment: Why use `xcopy` when PowerShell itself has [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item)? Its `-Exclude` is easier to use.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Basically the speed of transfer matters for me. I found somewhere that xcopy is fastest and so my team used it. Is it correct that xcopy is fastest of all? If not, the `Copy-Item` would be best bet

Comment: Possibly an issue of quoting. Try `"/Exclude:$excludeFilesPath"`

Comment: Does `$excludeFilesPath` contain spaces?

Comment: If the speed matters you may try robocopy. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Xcopy works only with a list of files, and can accept an array of excluded files from *.txt files
As a variant (possibly the worst way), you can previously create a list of files in EXCLUDE.TXT to bypass restrictions:

```
$DirsToExclude = @("C:\FILES\exclude1\","C:\FILES\exclude2\"); <#add here more dirs as you need#>
$FilesToExclude =(gci $DirsToExclude -file).FullName >> C:\temp\FilesToExclude.txt ;   
    xcopy "$($deploySourceRoot)*" $deployRoot /E /Y /Q /Exclude:C:\temp\FilesToExclude.txt
```